# Why is there a line through my window title text?

Tags: windows, windows-10, title-bar

I've seen this before, years ago, in an older version of Windows, but after a recent upgrade of Windows 10, it has appeared again.  My window title text has what looks like a debugging feature enabled to measure fonts.

[image]

Comment: Seriously, no one on Earth knows why this is happening?

Comment: Still nothing???

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue for months and could not find any solution online to fix it. i decided to go through all the applications i have installed that could affect my windows 10 theme only to find the culprit. **Windows Aero Glass** application. after uninstalling the issue as resolved. hope that helps you.